# Is there a way to track when tag edits were made?

Tags: support, tags, edits

I want to be able to identify when certain answers were posted relative to when certain tags were included with the question.

My curiosity is: I want to know if an answer uses a domain outside the scope of what the OP intended and the author of that answer edited the tags to include the domain they utilized in their answer.

I suspect there is a way to track the time stamps of when tag edits were made.  I just can't figure it out.

Comment: In SEDE you can find the tagedits in the PostHistory table, for posthistorytypeid's 3 and 6: http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/710455?tag=haskell but it is a bit unclear if that is what you need. Specially because @servy reads something completely different in your question...

Comment: @rene Why would you need an SEDE query just to get the time of when a tag was added to a question?  In addition to being way more work than just looking at the revision history, SEDE isn't updated in real time, so if it's not a fairly old edit that won't help you.

Comment: @Servy well, yes. If the OP is only interested in one question there is no need but I read they want to reason about answer being added after a tag appears. That does seem to suggest some query over a large set might be needed.

Comment: "unless I'm mistaken, tag edits look and feel different than a normal edit" You're mistaken.  They look and feel (and act and *are*) a normal edit.

Comment: @Servy suppose there are 100+ revisions and one wants to see only tag edits. In those cases, SEDE is the better way.

Comment: @rene The idea here is someone answers a SQL question, then later someone edits in a SQL Server tag, but the answer is Oracle specific.  The OP here wants to be able to see when the tag was edited in relative to when the answer was posted to see if the answerer missed the tag, or if it just wasn't there when they posted their answer.

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd I'm going to go out on a limb and say that even if there are quite a few revisions, it'll be less work to look through the revision history than to write an SEDE query to get the answer (especially considering the time lag for an SEDE query making it not even an option if the issue is recent).

Comment: @Servy considering your conviction, I'll assume you correct and refer to the dup target.  Thanks

Comment: Ok, either the edit history or [timeline](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/16770/timeline) will work.

Comment: @rene thanks for the suggestion as well.